# imitate load balancing programmatically

Tags: load-balancing

I have implemented some simple messaging system `IMS` for my own use inside the application, that allows sending and recieving message for objects.

I have a singleton object `IMSContext` that has a method `transfer` which is used to pass messages by every object

```
IMSContext.instance.transfer(message)
```

Also that `IMSContext` stores all `IMS` objects.

As I use sole method to transfer message, I want to imitate some kind of `load balancing` - assuming that this sole method is a bottleneck - when there are too much messages are being transferred I want to use some kind of mechanism that would move the flow of messages to another method...or maybe even object.

But I have no idea how to do it. Could recommend something or help with the approach?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean the sole method would be a bottleneck? Are you concerned with being CPU-bound and unable to take care of parallelism, or is this networked among multiple machines? If it's just within a single application using multiple method calls or multiple objects makes no difference and you're just creating more work for the system. But dealing with parallelism, multiple machines, and networking are all very different use cases.

Comment: On the surface of it, its not possible to 'split the load' when all the work is done on the same computer

Comment: @Ewan: Most computers nowadays have multiple cores, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: Oh yes, but "... To another method... Or object.."? I think the questioner is confused rather than asking about multithreading

Comment: @Ewan I just want to make some kind of imitation - I don't  have any particular issues with the current implementation - all clients are in separate threads + one singleton. I just want to make that singleton imitate real-life server with load balancing.

Comment: @BrianDHall It's the same machine and even the same application. I just want  load balancing network imitation. (similar like graphic diagrams with examples but only used inside the application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. But here goes.

Problem summary

- You have a Messaging class with method transfer
- You want to spread the calls to transfer over multiple instances of the Messaging class
- You want the calling code to be unaware of the many instances

first off. Don't use singletons.

second. wrap Messaging in a new class MessagingLoadBalanced which holds a list of Messaging instances. something like:

```
class MessagingLoadBalanced : IMessaging
{
    private List<Messaging> messagings;
    private int i = 0;

    Public void Transfer(object message)
    {
        messagings[i].Transfer(message);
        i++;
        if(i >= messagings.Length) { i=0;}
    }
}
```

lastly, use this new class in your calling code as if it was a normal IMessaging

Comment: Well, it seems close to what I want. Though I am planning to extend number of message instances depeding on the load. I get it.